# Hide Pager if bxslider has only 1 slide

Tags: slider, bxslider

I'm trying to add a class "disabled" to the pager if the slider has only 1 slide showing, and nothing to actually slide.

I'm sliding a div, not a list.

It's just a basic div:

```
<div class="bxslider2">
    <div class="wrap">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery for the slider:

```
 $('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
   mode: 'horizontal',
   speed: '180',
   pagerType:'full',
   pager:'true',
   captions: false
 });
```

I would like to not show the pager if there is only 1 slide showing.

Thanks for any help!

Justin

Answer (score 19):

I faced the same trouble and here is my solution: we should count how many child elements we have under .bxslider2 block

```
$(".bxslider2>.wrap").length
```

and if there is only one, then set option to 'false', otherwise to 'true'.

```
$('.bxslider2').bxSlider({
   mode: 'horizontal',
   speed: '180',
   pagerType:'full',
   pager: ($(".bxslider2>.wrap").length > 1) ? true: false,
   captions: false
 });
```

Hope it will helps.

Comment: not the best solution (and standard it would be '.bxslider > li'), but it does the trick, thanks

Comment: I used this to disable auto scrolling when there is only 1 slide

Comment: this wont work, if you have multiple slider elements on the same page and all of them are created by the same selector. given three bxslider  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();. The first two have 5 elements, the third only 3. then $(".bxslider>.item").length will return the total count of 13 elements.

Answer (score 5):

I use css to achieve this.

```
.bx-pager-item:first-of-type:last-of-type { 
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution if you have more than one bxslider on the page.

```
    $('.bxslider').each(function() {
      var options = {
        mode: 'fade',
      };
      if ($(this).find('li').length === 1) {
        options.pager = false;
      }
      $(this).bxSlider(options);
    });
```

Goes through each slider and finds if it has only one li. If so, add `pager: false` to the object passed to `bxSlider`.

Answer (score 0):

a nice way to solve this thing is to reload the object like that
and change the controls per number of the items :

```
    var slideQty = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 3,
        slideWidth: 110,
        slideMargin: 0,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        pager: false,
        moveSlides: 1,
        onSlideAfter: function ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) { NextSlide(oldIndex, newIndex); }

    });



    var count = slideQty.getSlideCount();
    if (count < 7) {
        slideQty.reloadSlider({
            controls : false,
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 3,
            slideWidth: 110,
            slideMargin: 0,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            pager: false,
            moveSlides: 1,
            onSlideAfter: function ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) { NextSlide(oldIndex, newIndex); }
        });
    }

    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me!!

```
var slider = $('#slider').bxSlider();

$('.bx-next, .bx-prev, .bx-pager a').click(function(){
     // time to wait (in ms)
     var wait = 1000;
     setTimeout(function(){
     slider.startAuto();
  }, wait);
});
```